# App crawler in Android Jetpack tool not working locally as mentioned in developers documentation

Tags: android, google-play-console, firebase-test-lab

I am using the following command:

```
java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --apk-file path/to/my/app.apk --android-sdk path/to/my/android/sdk
```

I followed the steps mentioned in the
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/crawler
but it's not even installing the app on the connected device, forget about crawling. Anything that I am missing?
I have also referred https://android.jlelse.eu/test-robo-scripts-locally-useful-for-firebase-test-lab-pre-launch-reports-41da83d5769f

Comment: You need to make sure you install the instrumentation apk first. Running `./gradlew connected<YourBuildFlavor>AndroidTest` should do that. Then run the crawler.

Comment: also i have same issue crawler dosent do any thing but the diffrenc is here i am using --app-package-name becuase my app is app bundle os i ahve istalled it on emulator and want to run crawler but no sucess i also run this with an other sample app architecture-components-samples but no luck seet the crawler log output

Comment: @Emmanuel can you elaborate on this? maybe send example or ref

Comment: The app crawler needs the instrumentation apk that is generated for your app. This is an apk that gets generated for you when running instrumentation tests. Running `connectedAndroidTest` (if no flavors are defined will generate and install the instrumentation apk). After that is done, then you can run the crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Try on an emulator Android 9, api28.

https://medium.com/@denysiakimov/how-to-run-android-app-crawler-testing-tool-a0d6f387e89e